# C++: Single instance of a dialog?

Tags: c++, singleton, wxwidgets

I have a dialog box I want to only exist once, as two different classes (MainFrame, which can open it outright, and Wizard, which can open it with settings brought in from the wizard itself) have to access it at any given time.  Ideally, I would like the user to be able to open the dialog with the Wizard, with everything filled out, then close it.  If they need to change settings, they should be able to open it with the MainFrame and edit it there.

The way I have it implemented currently has two different instances of the dialog box.  If it's opened from the MainFrame after the Wizard, the Mainframe one will have default values, while the Wizard one can also be open with values from the wizard.

I tried implementing singleton design pattern following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Explain-Cplusplus-Singleton-design-pattern) but attempting to open the Wizard or the dialog itself causes it to give an xC0000005 error.

MainFrame has access to both the Wizard and Dialog headers, and the Dialog has access to the Wizard header for the function that passes data from the Wizard to the Dialog (with Dialog forward-declared in Wizard's header).

I'm really not sure of the way to go forward with this, but any help is appreciated.  I can give code on my implementation if necessary.

Edit: Didn't do much outside of the linked URL, but it is developed on wxWidgets if that makes any difference.  Here's relevant code.

```cpp
Dialog.h

#include "Wizard.h"
class Dialog
{
private:
    Dialog() {}
    Dialog(Dialog const& copy) {}
    Dialog& operator=(Dialog const& copy) {}

    static Dialog* instance;

//many functions and variables

public:
    Dialog(wxWindow* parent) //more fields, generated by wxFormBuilder
    ~Dialog();

    Wizard* wizard;
    void SetRelative(Wizard* inWizard);

    static Dialog* GetInstance()
    {
        instance = new Dialog(NULL);
        return instance;
    }
};
```

```cpp
Dialog.cpp

#include "Dialog.h"

Dialog* Dialog::instance = 0;

Dialog::Dialog(wxWindow parent, etc.)
{
    //lots of stuff
}

//event handlers, helper functions

void Dialog::SetRelative(Wizard* inWizard)
{
    this->Wizard = inWizard
}
```

```cpp
Wizard.h

class Dialog;

class Wizard
{
public:
    Dialog* dialog;
}
```

```cpp
Wizard.cpp

#include "WizardSetup.h"
#include "WizardDialog.h"

Wizard::Wizard(wxWindow* parent, etc.)
{
//bunch of stuff
    dialog->GetInstance()
    dialog->SetRelative(this) <--------- hangs at this statement
}
```

```cpp
MainFrame.cpp

#include "Dialog.h"
#include "Wizard.h"

class MainFrame: public wxFrame
{
protected:
    Dialog* m_dialog;
    Wizard* m_wizard;

etc.
}
```

```cpp
MainFrame.cpp
#include "MainFrame.h"

MainFrame::MainFrame(wxWindow* parent, etc.)
{
//stuff here

m_dialog->GetInstance();
}

void MainFrame::menuDialogOnMenuSelection( wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    m_dialog->Show(); <-------- hangs here
}
```

Comment: *I can give code on my implementation if necessary.* yes please. Please read [example] before doing so. The more you can reduce the noise of your example, the easier it will be for us to help you. You may also mention what UI library you're using (qt, winapi, etc) if those are relevant to your problem.

Comment: Sorry, it's been a while and I wasn't sure if going singleton was the way or if a whole new approach would have been better.

Anyway, code added.  I have been doing the instance = 0, no dice.

Comment: To adhere to the singleton pattern you need to not have ANY public constructors. Also take a look at the difference between your `getInstance` and the linked example's `getInstance`. The logic for a singleton is "have I already created one of these? if not, create one. Either way, return the one that exists.". Right now you're creating a new `Dialog` on every call to `getInstance`. Not sure if that's your main issue, but it's definitely one of them.

Comment: `dialog->GetInstance()` this shouldn't compile. `GetInstance()` is supposed to be static. The call should be something like `Dialog* the_one_and_only_dialog = Dialog::GetInstance();` and `Dialog* another_pointer_to_the_same_dialog = Dialog::GetInstance();` The singleton `GetInstance()` function is like a degenerate factory function that only takes one order ("Dialog, please!") and only produces one thing.

Comment: Make sure your [example] actually reproduces the error please.

Comment: Forgot to change that.  I had removed it due to some unexpected error.

Moved the constructors to private, changed `_instance = new WizardSetupDialog(NULL);` to a full construction using the wxWidgets one, still has the error.

Comment: Wait my bad - `dialog->GetInstance();` is still valid. That should compile. I apologize.

Comment: Consider the `Dialog* dialog` pointer in your `Wizard` object. You never initialize it. It's an 8 (or 4) byte location in the memory of your `Wizard` object that's uninitialized. No telling what value it has. You need to explicitly tell it to point to the singleton object. `dialog = Dialog::GetInstance();` Same with any other pointers you want to your singleton `Dialog` - you need to assign the result of `Dialog::GetInstance()` to each of them. Otherwise `dialogue->some_function_of_the_dialog_class()` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also, strictly speaking, having a constructor for a singleton class be publicly accessible won't directly cause a crash or hang or compilation failure. But it sends mixed messages to the next guy who works on this about what you want your class to do ("It's supposed to be a singleton... unless you instantiate one that holds a `WxWindow*`?"). It's like if you have a military base with a very secure front gate: guards, checkpoints, pneumatic barriers, etc, but then a back gate with a sign that says "open to the public". It sends mixed messages.

Comment: Ugh.  I can't believe I missed doing that this entire past few hours!  It was forgetting to assign the result, of all things.  And of course it now behaves properly.  

Thank you for all the help.  If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Also yes I know the way I implemented it at first was messy, I like to try to get things working before cleaning them up.  Moving it now had no adverse effects, at least...

Comment: I generally agree with breaking things to start. That's how I learn as well. Although sometimes those prototypes you're developing with a smashy mindset end up not being prototypes a few months later when the sales department has made unrealistic promises to customers. I know at least one company with a 30 year old system like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three (immediate) issues with this code:

1. Your `Dialog::Dialog(WxWindow*)` constructor is public, which sends mixed signals about the nature of your singleton object. While not directly responsible for crashing or hanging, you're exposing your class to improper use that may violate the singleton contract (and thus indirectly cause crashes, hangs, or worse: silent errors) when The Next Guy (which might be you in a month) tries to maintain this code.
2. You're not checking for the existence of an already instantiated `Dialog` in your `Dialog::GetInstance()` function. You should have

```
static Dialog* GetInstance()
{
    if (instance == nullptr) instance = new Dialog(nullptr);
    return instance;
}
```

3. You're not assigning the various `Dialog*` member variables (such as `Wizard::dialog` and `MainFrame::m_dialog`) the address of your singleton `Dialog`. Be sure to do that:

```
// (in the Wizard constructor for example)
dialog = Dialog::GetInstance();
```

---

Addendum note: I think it's worth mentioning that the singleton pattern is often called an *anti*pattern. I'm not smart enough to understand why. It assumedly tends to cause some undesirable coding practices, and it's definitely cumbersome to deal with sometimes, but hey, whatever gets the job done. Just keep in mind that it's not necessarily the best tool for the job according to Some People.